# Does a bijection always generate a natural "induced" topology?

Tags: general-topology, open-map

Consider a topological space $(X_1, \tau_1)$ and a set $X_2$. Suppose as well that there existed some bijection $h$ from $X_1$ to $X_2$ (and viceversa).

Now suppose that we attempted to construct an "induced" topology for $X_2$, $\tau_2$, by considering a subset of $X_2$ to be an open set in $\tau_2$ if and only if it is the image of an open set in $\tau_1$ under the action of the bijection $h$. **Would this technique always generate a topology for $X_2$?** If not, are there any simple restrictions on the topological characteristics of $(X_1,\tau_1)$ that would make this work (i.e., compactness)?

Comment: Yes, this technique induces a topology on $X_2$. In fact, this technique can be generalized if $h$ is merely a surjection. We define $U \subseteq X_2$ to be open iff $h^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X_1$. $X_2$ is said to have the "quotient topology".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Your definition means that
$$\tau_2 = \{h(U) \mid U \in \tau_1\} .$$
It is very easy to verify that $\tau_2$ is a topology on $X_2$. This topology  makes $h$ a homeomorphism ($h$ is open by definition and continuous because $h^{-1}(h(U)) =U$) and it is the **only** topology on $X_2$ with this property. Indeed, let $\tau$ is a topology on $X_2$. Then $h : (X_1,\tau_1) \to (X_2,\tau)$ is open iff $\tau_2 \subset \tau$ and continuous iff $\tau \subset \tau_2$.

Comment: This is what is called a "[transport of structure](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_of_structure) (the structure here being the topology) from a set equipped with some type of structure to a "naked" set via some bijection. This way, your set inherits the same type of structure and your bijection becomes an isomorphism  (i.e. here, in the category of topological spaces: a homeomorphism).